# Importing Matrix Type Data into PBI from Excel

Tags: matrix, powerbi, visualization

I have a dataset which looks like this:

| Type | Study Name | UK | USA | Brazil |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Number | Study A | 10 | 7 | 19 |
| Number | Study B | 22 | 111 | 80 |
| Number | Study C | 100 | 99 | 200 |
| Date | Study A | 19/01/22 | 04/11/24 | 19/02/23 |
| Date | Study B | 12/08/23 | 16/03/25 | 19/11/22 |
| Date | Study C | 28/11/23 | 20/09/23 | 19/08/22 |
| Date 2 | Study A | 19/01/26 | 04/11/25 | 19/02/24 |
| Date 2 | Study B | 12/08/25 | 16/03/26 | 19/11/23 |
| Date 2 | Study C | 28/11/24 | 20/09/24 | 19/08/23 |

There are a couple of visualizations I would like to produce from this data set but I am struggling to import it into PBI with the correct data types.

Once imported I will need to perform some calculations/visualisations as I am trying to display the following things:

- Calculate no of countries below 3% of total number (i.e. for Study A 10+7+19 would be 100%)
- Time in months between the two date values.
- Have a view on one page with all three studies and see how these change with different filters.

Any advice or assistance on this would be greatly appreciated, I think that once I can import this data and make sense of it I should be able to create the list of visuals required.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A suggestion would be to Unpivot other columns on `Type` and `Study Name`. Then pivot on `Type`.

Example:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("bY67DoMwDEV/BWVG8iMJTcY+5i4dEUOrMnapYOjfYwckU5Eluop9rk/fu/v8eY1f17rHNL9/zVkSoTwnDdkN7WHlIolZx0TyJqwtXUuPFuWs+7hu3Z7T+H8rAxKUOgxAEsP2y8D+yOhxYsCkU4kdoAeOK0Ol6cCoC6cy9cUFMG94Lk3GNFyz68wuml2oUTu/aH6d+fkatTMMZhjMUKhhAQ==", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [Type = _t, #"Study Name" = _t, UK = _t, USA = _t, Brazil = _t]),
    #"Unpivoted Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(Source, {"Type", "Study Name"}, "Country", "Value"),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Unpivoted Columns", List.Distinct(#"Unpivoted Columns"[Type]), "Type", "Value"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Pivoted Column",{{"Number", Int64.Type}, {"Date", type date}, {"Date 2", type date}})
in
    #"Changed Type"
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Ignoring the `Source` line as this should be looking at your source, there is no mention of country column in the following steps, so the above should work fine with multiple/many other countries. Have you tested/tried the answer?

Comment: Yes!! Finally got it to work- apologies I'm awful with PBI